# vb.net add/remove days to date and change format

Tags: vb.net

```
Function GetFirstDayOfMonth(ByVal dtDate As Date) As DateTime
        Dim dtFrom As Date = dtDate
        dtFrom = dtFrom.AddDays(-(dtFrom.Day - 1))
        Return dtFrom
    End Function
```

i use this function to get the first day of a month and i call it here:

```
detail_fromdate = GetFirstDayOfMonth(DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy)
```

but its not changing the format to `dd-MM-yyyy`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please understand that dates have no format. It is the ToString or other methods that apply a formatting appearance to your date converting it to a string suitable to be displayed.

Your function could be written as

```
Function GetFirstDayOfMonth(ByVal dtDate As Date) As DateTime
    return new DateTime(dtDate.Year, dtDate.Month, 1)
End Function
```

and when you get the date back

```
Dim detail_fromdate As DateTime = GetFirstDayOfMonth(DateTime.Today)
Dim stringAsDateToBeDisplayed = detail_fromdate.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy")
```

or whatever format you want to display

By the way, your code works just because you have the Option Strict set to Off and this allows to pass a string when the GetFirstDayOfMonth expects a datetime.
Option Strict Off allows this automatic conversion from one type to another but more often this kicks you in unexpected ways if you don't pay a lot of attention to this issue. If it is not to late use [Option Strict On.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcd4xwzs.aspx)

Comment: 1+ ... except it is never too late to use Option Strict